# QField and Tab file

Tags: mapinfo, qfield

We use Mapinfo tab files and we like to use QField as our mobile application. Does QField support MapInfo tab file format?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used QField before. But I checked the [**supported data formats**](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/dataformat.html) page and TAB files aren't listed.

The formats currently supported:

> Spatialite ✔
>   Geopackage ✔
>   WMS    ✔
>   WFS    ✔
>   WFS-T  ✔
>   Postgis    ✔   Ssl support not yet implemented.
>   MBTiles    ✔
>   Shapefile  ✔
>   Tiff   ~   JPEG compression not yet supported.
>   ECW    ✘   License restricts usage.
>   MrSID  ✘   License restricts usage.

Interestingly, it looks like it may be supported, but  you just have to try it, and if not, just ask the developers to add it (not sure how lucky you'll be to get it added).

> If you don’t find your favorite data format on this table, please
>   check if it works and [adapt the list above](https://github.com/opengisch/QField-docs/edit/master/en/project-management/dataformat.rst) to share your findings. If
>   it does not work, please [open an issue](https://github.com/opengisch/OSGeo4A/issues). We will be happy to help you
>   with the implementation.

Comment: QGIS internally uses OGR/GDAL for accessing data sources. Because OGR/GDAL is just great many providers are available "out of the box" and have just never been tested and verified. For those that are not currently supported (and don't have any licensing like those listed as such) it's possible to add them. Having things added to QField - and any (open source) software - is only rarely luck but simply a matter of allocating required resources like manpower or organizing them, where money can often be a very good mean to organize things.